# AppFabric NHibernate provider does not forward requests to DB if Cache Cluster fails

Tags: .net, windows, caching, appfabric, nhibernate-caches

I've given an assignment to setup *AppFabric* for 2nd level caching using *NHibernate AppFabric Cache Provider* (By [Simon Taylor](https://github.com/SimonTaylor/NHibernate.Caches.AppFabric)). I've successfully setup and it's working. However in a failure scenario, if the Cache Cluster or simply the whole service stops working (Assuming I have only 1 cache server) the application requests don't forward to database. When I restart the Cluster, the application works as intented.

So, despite having only 1 cache server isn't practically right, what should I do to make my application use DB in such failure cases?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what happens when the cache server is down? Do you get an error, or a return of null, or ..?

Comment: thnx for ur answer. simply a mapping method throws exception because it cannot find the values requested as hibernate tryin to connect cache and it's down. actually this is irrelevant because i'm wondering (and searching for an explanation) if this is because the NHibernate cache provider? I mean, am I missing some config settings or smth to make it forward the queries to DB instead of cache server when cache is down?

Comment: It seems after 10 years still no solution for this issue. If cache server is down then NHibernate throws exception and does not try to forward to DB instead.